# List global variables in executable

Tags: c, xcode, macos, gcc, otool

How can I dump all the global variables and the address offsets in my executable?

This is on os x, app developed with xcode compiled with gcc.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## If Compiled to Mach-O

Either use [`otool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/otool.1.html) or the `cctools`.

## If Compiled to ELF

You should be able to do this with `objdump` and/or `readelf`.

I don't have a *nix system at hand here, but `objdump -s -j .data` should be getting you rather close enough.

Comment: It's an OS X application. It's not compiled to ELF. And there's no objdump unless you install libelf and elftools.

Comment: How do I use otools to get the global variables?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get a list of global variables and their offsets from an executable on macOS (original question) is to use the `nm` tool. Without any additional keys, it gives the variables and their offsets.

Example:

```
$ nm <some binary>
...
                 U __ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
                 U __ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE
000000010006e248 s __ZTVN7testing17TestEventListenerE
000000010006e1c0 s __ZTVN7testing22EmptyTestEventListenerE
000000010006dfa8 s __ZTVN7testing31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceE
000000010006d860 S __ZTVN7testing32ScopedFakeTestPartResultReporterE
000000010006d8d8 S __ZTVN7testing4TestE
...
```

Check `man nm` for the explanation of the codes like `U`, `s`, `S`, etc.

---

In case you also want to look for string constants, there is another tool `strings`:

```
$ strings <some binary> -o -t x
```

will give you a list of string literals and their offsets.

See `man strings` for more details.